How to iterate over a container of pairs of pairs in C++?
If I have a vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>>, what would you suggest as the most concise method to iterate over them, having access to all four elements in pairs, with creating as less local variables as possible?
I wish I could do something like this, but this does not compile:
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>> vec = {
        {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
        {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}
    };

    for (const auto& [[a, b], [c, d]] : vec)
        // do stuff with a, b, c, d


Do not use std:pair this way. std::pair or std::tuple is great when doing generic programing, what you are not doing. In this context is is much much better to use struct with explicit names of fields. If you will use struct you will notice that structured binding is not necessary.

if you need help with code that causes a compiler error you should include a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message in the quesiton

if you want to access all 4 elements as if they were elements of a 4-element array, consider to use a 4-element array. Or do what Marek suggested and give the elements proper names.

i can't use it as a 4-element array due to meaningful relationship between pair members. thank you all, i wrapped everything into a struct with another struct inside for the inner pair.

for (const auto& [p1, p2] : pairs) { auto [a, b] = p1; auto [c, d] = p2; /*..*/}

You can access all 4 elements with exactly 1 local variable for (const auto& e : vec) { // use e.first.first, e.first.second, e.second.first, e.second.second }.  Your request of "less local variables as possible" doesn't match the code snippit you provided.  Use the approach Marek suggested.
